# Disable external hard disk auto-open/autoplay at every startup!

Tags: mount, nautilus, usb-drive, external-hdd, automount

I've already run this:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount-open false
```

and uncheck automount & automount-open in dconf-editor but problem remain.

Edit: I run Ubuntu-Mate 16.04 if this help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the System Menu > Preferences > Personal > File Management [image]

#### Here you have multiple option to select.

Comment: Just what I was looking for, though it took a couple of days of sporadic searching before I found the right question to ask!

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu 16.04 LTS in the (unity) **system settings** you can disable actions on media if you go to the "*details*" menu:

[image]